# Myphpadmin Hiding Databases

Tags: mysql

I have a client that wants to use myphpadmin to manage his mysql database 5.x on my server. I found this article on how to hide databases from myphpadmin but I don't like this because if I don't specify the databases to hide then every time I add a new database it because available to the client through myphpadmin.

Article: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/hide-databases-phpmyadmin/

Command to hide a database in the myphpadmin config.inc.php file:

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'hidedb1|hidedb2|etc...';
```

I also created a separate username and password in mysql to.

Is there a way to reverse this so I can tell myphpadmin what database to only show for this login?

Thanks,

Frank G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL user will see only the databases on which he has access right. You can test it

```
mysql> create database test_db;
mysql> grant all privileges on test_db.* to test_user@'%' identified by "password";
```

After that login with test_user and you will see only test_db database

> What do I do if the user has three database that are already populated. How do I give him just access to those three?

first of all revoke all privileges

```
mysql> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM test_user@'%';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

and then grant to necessary db/tables/columns

Comment: What do I do if the user has three database that are already populated. How do I give him just access to those three?

Comment: okay I create a test db called "test123" and then I did the grant all priv to user test_user with the password set to password. Then I tried to login to phpmyadmin and it wont let me. I know the db is there and the user I see both. I also removed the phpmyadmin config file so that wont cause problems. But still wont let me in. Any suggestions?

Comment: well that was educational. I figured it out and that is very helpful for future things like this so a big thank you to you for your help!!!! Thanks!

Comment: You can see all privileges with "SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'host';"

Comment: Can you tell me this. Is grant the only no no to give permissions to? Meaning if I create a user from your code above is the pretty safe to do? Thanks again!

Comment: what do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: Well setting up a user they way you show is that the best way to setup a user with permissions? I always pull Grant from all users but sometimes wonder about all the other permissions insert, alter, drop etc... Ate bare minimum what does the average user need to function with mysql?

Comment: A typical mysql user should have access for insert/update/delete records from db, for e.g wordpress user. If you have some special requirements then you should split the access, imho